# Method gets called multiple times in a second, but it should only be run once in a small time span

Tags: iphone, swift, uikit

I'm calling a method from a DeviceMotion callback using the accelerometer. The problem is that the method gets called multiple times in a second but should only be run once within a second or two. I've tried using NSLock and a simple bool to block execution, but it doesn't seem to work. Maybe the time between the function calls is too small?

```
motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdates(to: backgroundQueue) {
    (data, error) in

    if let error = error {
        print(error)
    }

    if let data = data {
        if data.acceleration.z >= 2 {
            self.omxPause()
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the function that gets called:

```
func omxPause() {
    objc_sync_enter(self)
    defer {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime(uptimeNanoseconds: 2 * NSEC_PER_SEC)) {
            objc_sync_exit(self)
        }
    }

    makeApiCall("omx", arguments: ["command": "pause"], httpProtocol: .POST) { _ in }
}
```

Comment: Use [`accelerometerUpdateInterval`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMMotionManager_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CMMotionManager/accelerometerUpdateInterval) to throttle the rate at which your block gets invoked with data?

Answer (score 2):

The `startAccelerometerUpdates(to:withHandler:)` function gets called every time the accelerometer receives new data which happens quite often. That will also trigger your `omxPause` function every time there is new data from the accelerometer.

This is what the documentation says about the startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue function:

> Because the processed events **might arrive at a high rate**, using the
>   main operation queue is not recommended.

So, if you want to call the method only once or twice in a couple of seconds, placing it within the startAccelerometerUpdates function probably isn't the best idea.